# deploy similar ruby on rails code to multiple server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a rails app looking good on my localhost. Now I want to deploy it to multiple server (one load balancer, and two application server to be exact, with possible increase in the future), and somehow I'm lost. This would be my first time deploying a web by myself, so I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge.

I want all application server to run exactly same code.
And when I create a new content, I want the new content to be stored on each server's database instance (MySQL). So when I took down one server for maintenance and updating, the rest of the server could serve users with exact same content. I've read that capistrano could help me with this, but somehow I managed to get lost in learning how to do this. So, how should I proceed from here? How should the capistrano recipe look like, and do I have to tweak database.yml in my rails also?

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use roles to deploy the same application to multiple servers.
Assuming you're using the multistage extension, define the roles in `production.rb`:

```
server1 = 'appserver1.tld'
server2 = 'appserver2.tld'
server3 = 'webserver1.tld'

role :app, server1, server2
role :web, server3
```

The web server will run on servers specified by the `:web` role.

The app layer will run on servers specified by the `:app` role.

If you run migrations or other DB operations during deploy, you should also specify a server under the `:db` role. For example:

```
role :db, 'dbserver.tld', :primary => true
```

You may have multiple DB servers, but by specifying one as the primary server capistrano will only run DB operations on that server.

In your `deploy.rb`, you can also create tasks that run only for certain roles. For example:

```
task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
end
```

In the above example, `:except => { :no_release => true }` means that it will only run if at least one release exists on the server being deployed to.

[This wiki article](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-from-the-beginning) may be of further help to you.

Comment: oh wow, thanks. That's quite a complete explanation. And that's also a nice link you give. Once again, Thank you very much. I'll get to experimenting right away.

Comment: And btw one more question, is the :web role means the server running nginx in my case?

Comment: I believe that capistrano supports apache by default, but there is a capistrano-nginx gem that may be of use to you. https://github.com/ivalkeen/capistrano-nginx

Comment: Thanks once again. So it means, I don't have to run nginx (or apache) instance in every server? only the server I assign :web role in?

Comment: Yes, the `nginx:reload` task that is part of that gem will only run for the `:web` role, and the same for capistrano's built-in apache tasks.